# Material UI (dateTime picker) : Invalid Date Format message after submission

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, material-ui, jsx

I am using Material Ui **DateTime** picker in a form. After submitting the form, I get the following error:

> Invalid Date Format

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CR96.png)

I am using JSON Server in my react app for saving data.

**This is the output Element for the DateTime picker on DOM.**

```
<input aria-invalid="false" readonly="" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiInput-input" value="March 16th 08:50 a.m.">
```

This is data on db.json.

```
{
  "text": "study",
  "day": "2022-03-16T05:20:00.000Z",
  "reminder": true,
  "id": 1
}
```

This is my code for Add date.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import DateFnsUtils from "@date-io/date-fns";
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider } from "@material-ui/pickers";
import "date-fns";
import { DateTimePicker } from "@material-ui/pickers";

const AddTask = ({ onAdd }) => {

const [day, setDay] = useState(new Date());

const onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  onAdd({ day });
  setDay("");
};
return (
<form className="add-form" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
 <div className="form-control">
    <label>Day & time</label>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DateTimePicker
        disableToolbar
        variant="inline"
        value={day}
        onChange={(day) => {
          setDay(day);
        }}
        autoOk
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
  </div>
</form>
);
};
```

I would appreciate it if you help me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will probably not break if you remove the `setDay("");` line from onSubmit. Why do you need it after all?

Comment: Thanks. my problem solved. I was using <input type="text" /> before and I forget to remove setDay(" );